# Mixed metaphor in notification bar close

Tags: feature-request, notifications

When the notification bar is closed, it fades and then disappears. The fade metaphor is gradual removal, but the bar's size remains the same during the fade. It is then removed in one go, which jarringly pops the rest of the page to the top.

It would make more sense to either

1. Just instantly close the bar.
2. Decrease the height of the bar at the same rate as the fade, making the gradual metaphor consistent.

Comment: This seems more like a feature request then a bug?

Comment: From a UI perspective it might probably be called a bug. I'd assign this a very low priority, though.

Comment: I noticed this too.  It is a little jarring.  But not overly important.

Comment: YOU QUESTION MY JQUERY CODE?!  Yeah, it can be jarring - I'll play with it :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like the Looney Tunes exit: [booooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo POOF!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_d8ROhH3_vs) Didn't everybody think that when they saw the banner leave?